# How do I condense "Show Applications" from two screen to one?

Tags: appmenu

I have enough space on the first screen to show all apps. I just don't how to get the second screen to the first screen.

Is it even possible?

Thanks ahead for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag icons from the second screen to the first screen, until it is full. If you need to place more icons there than there is available space, then you will need to combine some of them in groups.

It is a matter of drag and drop. In recent versions of Gnome Shell, you fully decide where icons go.

Comment: Thanks, was rather easy at that, hmm nice name "tough steel"